# For common emitter configuration of a PNP transistor why is current 0 when emitter-collector voltage is 0?

Tags: transistors

For common emitter configuration of a PNP transistor why is collector current 0 when emitter-collector voltage is 0? Does'nt the emitter-base voltage affect it?

Comment: Which current, emitter, collector or base current?

Comment: Collector current @MartinZabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero volts across collector and emitter can only mean zero current into the collector. It's basic ohms law.

There may indeed be base emitter current flowing but that current flows out thru the emitter (NPN) and not the collector.

If collector emitter voltage is held at zero volts and the base voltage is significant then the collector base junction is becoming forward biased and current will flow from the collector so maybe this is what you allude to?

This is the same for both NPN and PNP transistors.

Comment: But in case of common base configuration the collector current is not 0 even when base current is 0.Why is it so?

Comment: If there is voltage across collector emitter then, at the very least, there will be leakage current.

Comment: Could you please explain this:- In common base configuration suppose no collector-base voltage exists is there but a emitter-base voltage exists,still a significant collector current exists.But for a common emitter configuration suppose no collector-emitter voltage exists but a emitter-base voltage exists then no current is present as collector current...why is it so?

Comment: This is the diagram I was referring to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv2tZi5C2v0&list=PLYVDsiuOZP5pIrz7YXgTavrdbioCZDBAT&index=11

Comment: And this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDDvcSoUIS4&index=8&list=PLYVDsiuOZP5pIrz7YXgTavrdbioCZDBAT

Comment: Yes that is what I was "alluding to" I guess

Comment: The two scerios are both valid - for the common base scenario because collector is, in effect, hard-wired to the base (0V between them), the transistor looks like a diode with the emitter being the cathode thus, if the emitter voltage is lower than the base/collector voltage, current will flow based on the diode equation and saturation will be about 0.7V to 1V. For the common emitter scenario, I believe you now understand it to be reverse current flowing from the base i.e. not a current that is normal for conventional transistor operation - it's called BJT saturation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the circuit you are asking about because applying an external short circuit is the only sure way to force the c-e voltage to 0 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3wyqp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this circuit, the collector current is not necessarily 0. If the base voltage, supplied by V1, goes negative by more than a few 100 mV, then the b-c junction will be forward biased and current will flow from the collector to base, producing a positive collector current (under the passive sign convention).

Comment: This is the diagram I was referring to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDDvcSoUIS4&index=8&list=PLYVDsiuOZP5pIrz7YXgTavrdbioCZDBAT

Comment: And this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv2tZi5C2v0&list=PLYVDsiuOZP5pIrz7YXgTavrdbioCZDBAT&index=11

Comment: Could you explain why is current 0 when voltage is 0 in one and not 0 in the other (in the videos)

Comment: So according to you its not necessarily 0.Right?

Comment: The OP actually asked for a PNP transistor, but the principal is the same, just a negative voltage at the base.

Comment: @MartinZabel, thanks for pointing that out. I think I've fixed the diagram and text to match.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, please edit your question to include the important information from the videos so people can understand the question without having to watch 20 minuts of video.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, note that when talking about common base, he biases the collector negative with respect to the base. And he biases the emitter positive. So there is a potential difference from emitter to collector in that circuit.

Comment: But even in the common emitter case he biases the base positive and collector negative.....

Comment: For PNP common emitter, if you want it in active mode you need to bias the base more negative than the collector.